# Click button push to another view controller with automatically highlight Tab Button Item

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

When I click the cross button in more view controller the action will push to home view controller.

[image: image1]

But the tab bar did not automatically highlight the home tab bar. The result I want is like this

[image: image2]

The code below is the action push to home view controller

```
-(void)tapDetected{
    HomeMainViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "homeVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: I have place your images inline so it's easier to see what the problem is. Maybe you could reduce the large image to just the relevent detail as there's a lot of empty space there. Also can you show your code for what you have attempted in order to rectify the problem.

Comment: thanks for the guide =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using a UITabBarController.
If yes, try this :

```
    UITabBarController* vc = (UITabBarController*) self.parentViewController;

    if( vc && [vc isKindOfClass:[MainTabViewController class]] )
    {
        [vc setSelectedIndex:0];
    }
```

Comment: I should put this code in the More View Controller or Tab Bar View Controller?

Comment: MoreViewController is a child of the UITabBarController (again, assuming you are using this controller). So parentViewController will return a UITabBarController. You just apply a cast to access it's setSelectedIndex method.

Comment: Also, instead of just "0", you should declare a constant, just to get clean code.